# Two-way ANOVA/GLM for 2x3 incomplete factorial design

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, experiment-design

I am designing a within-group study with two factors (**fixed novelty**, levels: *old*, *new*; and **indexical novelty**, levels: *veridical*, *statistical*, *new*; so a 2x3). Now, ideally, I would just cross these factors to be able to run a classical two-way ANOVA for

```
          Indexical
       |  V  |  S  |  N  |
F  ----------------------|
i  O   | OV  | OS  | ON  |
x  -----------------------
e  N   | NV  | NS  | NN  |
d  -----------------------
```

However, in my case, the factors cannot be fully crossed. Specifically, NV (i.e., new:veridical) is logically impossible due to the specifics of what I am looking at. To the best of my knowledge, this should mean that we cannot run a two-way ANOVA on these data (provided that we are really interested in the interactions here). Now, I did just simulate a data set like this and ran some analyses in R to see what the results would look like and, from what I have seen, the results would look perfectly fine and interpretable. But, again to the best of my knowledge, this should be statistically invalid (please correct me if I am wrong here). The question then is, what would be a good strategy to analyse these data?

Technically speaking, veridical & statistical could be considered nested (both are "old" but in different ways, so to speak) and I could make this a 2x2 nested design, but that would fundamentally not solve the problem, because I am very much interested in the interactions + between-condition comparisons here. Particularly, I am interested in between-conditions comparisons of (OV v OS v ON v NS), with NN being used as a sort of sanity check.

Other than that, I suppose I could fit a GLM to these data, although that would be regrettable because I am very much interested in the between-condition comparisons, too. My sort of 'last resort', currently, would be to eliminate the 2x3 design and code the data differently such that we can do a comparison between five groups, so to speak, although, again, I am not entirely sure if that is a good approach.

Any input on how to deal with incomplete factorials would be greatly appreciated.

Best wishes